# How to write a shell script which executes at a given time

Tags: bash

I want to write a BASH script such that it sorts my downloads folder at a given time daily.
It sorts it as follows:

> .mp3 .aac .m4a .m4b .aiff .wav .flac --> Music and Audiobooks
>   .mp4 .mov .flv .mkv .3gp .avi .ogg .ogv .drc .mng .wmv .yuv .m4v -->
>   Videos .pdf .doc .docx .xls .ppt --> Documents and Books
>   .* --> Misc

Here "Music and Audiobooks", "Videos" , "Documents and Books" and "Misc" are folders.
Apologies for the bad formatting.

Comment: You can use a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to execute your script at scheduled time (Unix/Mac).

Comment: `man 5 crontab` will help with your `cron` endeavor

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your question is about how to schedule it rather than how to write it since you have not posted any code at all.

The scheduling can be done within the bash script but that would be pretty atypical.  Instead, simply use cron to schedule the script to run at whatever interval you choose.  You can read more information on cron here:
[Cron](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205)